# Page crashes after trying to execute JS function on a table

Tags: javascript

I have a huge (I believe) table with 728 rows and 13 columns for each row. I am trying to sort the table by using the function below, but the page crashes and Chrome displays this message:

> You can wait for it to become responsive or exit the page.

***Sorting function:***

```
w3.sortHTML = function(id, sel, sortvalue) {
var a, b, i, ii, y, bytt, v1, v2, cc, j;
a = w3.getElements(id);
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        cc = 0;
        y = 1;
        while (y == 1) {
            y = 0;
            b = a[i].querySelectorAll(sel);
            for (ii = 0; ii < (b.length - 1); ii++) {
                bytt = 0;
                if (sortvalue) {
                    v1 = b[ii].querySelector(sortvalue).innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                    v2 = b[ii + 1].querySelector(sortvalue).innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    v1 = b[ii].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                    v2 = b[ii + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                }
                /******* custom *******/
                if (v1 === '-') {
                    v1 = 'zzzzz';
                }
                if (v2 === '-') {
                    v2 = 'zzzzz';
                }
                /******* custom *******/
                if ((j == 0 && (v1 > v2)) || (j == 1 && (v1 < v2))) {
                    bytt = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bytt == 1) {
                b[ii].parentNode.insertBefore(b[ii + 1], b[ii]);
                y = 1;
                cc++;
            }
        }
        if (cc > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
};
```

It works perfectly fine on smaller tables.

**Is there a coding way to make it work on large tables?**

Comment: This is just a thought, but try and do all your "toLowerCase();" changes to the data before it is sorted. Or, take out those functions for the moment and see if it speeds up.

Comment: I know that you are trying to develop this, but I suggest you to use existing librariies like https://datatables.net/

Comment: @vr_driver I tried already - same result

Comment: Four nested loops?  What sorting algorithm are you using?  Perhaps it's time to use a more efficient sorting algorithm.  As well as store your data in memory instead of in the DOM, so you can efficiently perform operations directly on the data and then just re-render the DOM from the data.

Comment: @Tushar Have you used it on big tables? How did it work?

Comment: Oh I have used this for records over 2,000 and had pagination as well. It worked smoothly. all I suggest is you dont want to spend time on something that is already there. Save that time, and use it somewhere else

Comment: @Tushar all I can say is: Thank You!

Comment: Does it resolved your issues?

Comment: @Tushar Yes it did